# How to add lore through an Addon

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

How do I add lore to a custom item on Minecraft Bedrock Edition through an Addon?

This is my code right now as a test.

```
{
    "pools": [
        {
            "entries": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "name": "minecraft:diamond",
                    "weight": 1,
                    "functions": [
                    {
                        "function": "set_lore",
                        "lore": [
                            "Big Stick has been handed down",
                            "for generations from King to Prince",
                            "until it went missing four score ago"
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

I have looked at both the official Microsoft documentation "*Loot and Trade Table Functions*" and the Bedrock Wiki "*Item Functions*."

The code is located in loot_tables/entity/mob.json

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered this for me and I'll share it here for anyone wondering.

You can edit the name, lets say the diamond. Rename the "minecraft:display_name" to "Diamond\nYour lore."

```
"minecraft:display_name": {
"value": "Diamond\nYour lore"
},
```

I did some research and it looks like "set_lore" isn't usable.
Minecraft uses lore in Minecraft Java Edition but Bedrock Edition uses the "\n" method.

You can see an example of this on the hotbar, hover over the enchanted book feather falling.

Java edition will say,

```
Enchanted Book
```

Bedrock Edition will say,

```
 Enchanted Book
Feather Falling I
```